# Ratchet Symfony2.2

Tags: php, symfony, real-time, symfony-2.2, ratchet

I am trying to create a real time Symfony app using Ratchet but I dont know where shoud I put my WampServerInterface and my server script (in a symfony service or just a class somewhere) and how should I call it from my appController

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to configure your provider as a service and inject it into the controller with constructor or setter injection.

you can aswell inject the whole container and get it from there but this is not recommended for performance and testability reasons.

Comment: could you give me more details plz

Comment: could you give me more details please

Answer (score 1):

First of all you would need to run ratchet server from command line.

You may chose to use symfony CLI for that as that would be the easiest way to get you started. I have not tested any of the following code, but something like the following would do.

```
<?php
namespace MyOrg\MyBundle\Command
{

    use 
        // Symcony CLI
        Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument,
        Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface,
        Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption,
        Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface,
        Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand,

        // Ratchet classes are used with full paths in execute() 

        // Your ratchet app class (e.g. https://github.com/cboden/Ratchet-examples/blob/master/src/Ratchet/Website/ChatRoom.php)
        MyOrg\MyBundle\MyRatchetAppClass;        

    class RatchetServerCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
    {

        protected function configure(){
            $this
                ->setName('myorg:ratchet')
                ->setDescription('Start ratchet server');
        }

        protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
        {

            $loop   = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
            $app = new MyRatchetAppClass();

            // Set up our WebSocket server for clients wanting real-time updates

            $webSock = new \React\Socket\Server($loop);

            $webSock->listen(88, 'YOURSERVER.COM');

            $webServer = new \Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
                new \Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
                    new \Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
                        new \Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                            $app
                        )
                    )
                ),
                $webSock
            );

            $loop->run();            
        }
    }
}
```

Then start the server using symfony cli:

```
php app/console myorg:ratchet
```

At the end of this, you would have a ratchet server running on port 88.

After that, use a websocket library to connect and test. I am using [autobahnjs] in my example below:

```
ab.connect(
   // The WebSocket URI of the WAMP server
   'ws://yourserver.com:88',

   // The onconnect handler
   function (session) {
      alert('Connected');
   },

   // The onhangup handler
   function (code, reason, detail) {
      alert('unable to connect...');
   }
);
```